# Moodle 3.7 & Apache & reverse proxy results ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, moodle

Moodle 3.7 Apache with reverse proxy results ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I have an SSL site with following vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>     


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName moodle.site.com:443

SSLEngine on
SecAuditEngine On
RewriteEngine On

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://101.102.103.104:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://101.102.103.104:80/

</VirtualHost>                                  
</IfModule>
```

I also redirect all 80 port requests to SSL port.

The command

```
curl -I https://moodle.site.com/
```

results:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Fri, 09 Aug 2019 19:13:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
Location: https://moodle.site.com
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

In Moodle config.php I have:

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://moodle.site.com';
$CFG->reverseproxy = true;
$CFG->sslproxy  = 1;
```

Any idea why I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error in Google Chrome, when I try to open https://moodle.site.com URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had 4 problems, so I had to fix them (command line commands should be executed as root or use sudo):

**1) mod_ssl Apache module was not activated.** Test in the command line, if mod_ssl is active:

```
apache2ctl -M | grep ssl
```

Should display this (if active):

```
ssl_module (shared)
```

**FIX** (enable mod_ssl in the command line):

```
a2enmod ssl
# Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
# Module setenvif already enabled
# Considering dependency mime for ssl:
# Module mime already enabled
# Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
# Enabling module socache_shmcb.
# Enabling module ssl.
# See /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz on how to configure SSL and create self-signed certificates.
# To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
# systemctl restart apache2
```

**2) I use the Header directive in Apache SSL conf file, like this:**

```
# Guarantee HTTPS for 180 days including sub domains 
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains"
```

Because of this mod_headers Apache module is required, it was not activated. Test  in the command line, if mod_headers is active:

```
apache2ctl -M | grep headers
```

Should display this (if active):

```
headers_module (shared)
```

**FIX** (enable mod_headers in the command line):

```
a2enmod headers
```

**3) I had to use https ProxyPass URL instead of http in Apache vhost conf file :**

Wrong:

```
ProxyPass / http://101.102.103.104:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://101.102.103.104:80/
```

**GOOD:**

```
ProxyPass / https://101.102.103.104/
ProxyPassReverse / https://101.102.103.104/
```

**4) Had to turn on SSLProxyEngine directive to use SSL in ProxyPass in Apache vhost conf file.**

**FIX:**
Added SSLProxyEngine on in /etc/apache2/sites-available/myvhost.conf

```
SSLProxyEngine on
```